# jQuery: How to paint text in different colors?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to append some text items to div element and paint them in different colors.

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].Id <= 2)
        $("#div3").append('<p>' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>').css('color', 'red');
    else if (data[i].Id > 2 && data[i].Id <= 4)
        $("#div3").append('<p>' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>').css('color', 'green');
    else
        $("#div3").append('<p>' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>').css('color', 'blue');
}
```

But, they are all blue.

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: what is data[i] ??? make a fiddle

Comment: It's not important. It's an object.

Comment: also make sure all of the conditions are being met also and that it isn't always going into the block where the color is being made blue.
right now whatever color gets set last is the color that the entire #div3 will show, because the color of the entire div is being changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appendTo()` instead:

```
 $('<p>' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>').appendTo("#div3").css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're applying the colors to #div3, not to the p tags inside it. That's why the last one applies to all p's. To fix it you could give a class to each p, and specify the color there. Or select the  p tag via jquery and apply the color that way.

Comment: Or use appendTo(). Anyway, +1 for providing the reason why OP's code not working as he expected it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#div3").append('<p style="color:red">' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>');
```

Comment: I see. But, could it be written better because the color is inside the code. What if I want to use some .css file?

Comment: @tesicg then you can use the class name instead of style.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving each 'p' a class and abstracting the styling to css?
or try giving each p element an id depending on the index? like this;

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (data[i].Id <= 2){
       $("#div3").append('<p id="p' + i + '">' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>')
       $("#p" + i).css('color', 'red');
   }else if (data[i].Id > 2 && data[i].Id <= 4){
       $("#div3").append('<p id="p' + i + '">' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>')
       $("#p" + i).css('color', 'green');
   }else{
       $("#div3").append('<p id="p' + i + '">' + data[i].FirstName + '</p>')
       $("#p" + i).css('color', 'blue');
   }
}
```